# Hotkeys to override default Windows shortcuts don't always work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have hotkeys defined to override the default solo Windows key behavior as well as the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut to launch an alternate file explorer app. Most of the time it works, but sometimes it doesn't. I haven't been able to determine a pattern to when it fails. When it does fail, the behavior seen is that the default Windows file explorer is launched. I was able to grab the key history from the most recent time it failed.

Is there anything I can add to my script or do differently that might make my custom shortcut more reliable?

AHK Code:

```
#SingleInstance force
#NoTrayIcon
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SetTitleMatchMode, 2  ; match anywhere in the title
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
GroupAdd, grpExplorer, ahk_class CabinetWClass
GroupAdd, grpExplorer, ahk_class ExploreWClass
GroupAdd, grpExplorer, ahk_class #32770
~LWin::Send {Blind}{vkFF}
~RWin::Send {Blind}{vkFF}
LWin UP::
RWin UP::
    if (A_PriorKey = "LWin" || A_PriorKey = "RWin")
    {
        SendInput, {F13}
    }
    return
#e UP::
    explExe := "C:\PortableApps\Explorer++Portable\Explorer++Portable.exe"
    if (FileExist(explExe))
    {
        IfWinExist, ahk_class Explorer++
        {
            WinActivate
        }
        else
        {
            Run, %explExe%
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Run, c:\windows\explorer.exe /e, ::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}
        WinWait, ahk_group grpExplorer, , 5
        WinActivate
    }
    return
$!#e UP::
    Run, c:\windows\explorer.exe /e, ::{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}
    WinWait, ahk_group grpExplorer, , 5
    WinActivate
    return
```

And here is the key history dump. It looks like the keys are being recognized just fine.

```
Window: C:\AHK\KeyRemapping.ahk - AutoHotkey v1.1.33.02
Keybd hook: yes
Mouse hook: yes
Enabled Timers: 0 of 0 ()
Interrupted threads: 0
Paused threads: 0 of 0 (0 layers)
Modifiers (GetKeyState() now) = 
Modifiers (Hook's Logical) = 
Modifiers (Hook's Physical) = 
Prefix key is down: no

NOTE: To disable the key history shown below, add the line "#KeyHistory 0" anywhere in the script.  The same method can be used to change the size of the history buffer.  For example: #KeyHistory 100  (Default is 40, Max is 500)

The oldest are listed first.  VK=Virtual Key, SC=Scan Code, Elapsed=Seconds since the previous event.  Types: h=Hook Hotkey, s=Suppressed (blocked), i=Ignored because it was generated by an AHK script, a=Artificial, #=Disabled via #IfWinActive/Exist, U=Unicode character (SendInput).

VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5B  15B h   d   12.20   LWin            
FF  000 i   d   0.00    not found       
FF  000 i   u   0.00    not found       
45  012     d   0.45    e               
45  012     u   0.11    e               File Explorer
5B  15B h   u   0.09    LWin            
01  000     d   5.50    LButton         
01  000     u   0.22    LButton         C:\AHK\KeyRemapping.ahk - AutoHotkey v1.1.33.02
74  03F     d   1.44    F5              
Press [F5] to refresh.
```

Answer (score 0):

Never had any issues (and I use <kbd>WinKey</kbd> a lot), try running the script with UI Access. <sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Program.htm#Installer_uiAccess)</sup>